# Question about a phrase with the Polish case genetive (dopełniacz)

Tags: grammar, cases, polish

in the following sentence:

```
"Teraz idę do żabki po sok"
```

What is the function of the genitive case applied on the noun "żabka"?

I'm aware that with the preposition "do", especially regarding a location, the genitive case is used to decline the following nouns. And I'm aware that verbs and prepositions go with specific cases.

But can someone explain the grammatical function of the genitive in this sentence, and the grammatical reasoning behind why it's this case and not another that is used?

I would appreciate a thorough, detailed explanation. If you happen to be a grammar nerd, I sincerely encourage you to answer, your response will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that it has a "grammatical function" rather than being a historical accident?

Comment: The word is genitive, not genetive. [apply to, not on]

Comment: @Lambie If you have suggested edits to typos, you can use the "Edit" feature and have your edits reviewed and applied to the post.

Comment: _Do_ is [found in all the Slavic languages](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/do) as a preposition with the meanings “[up] to” and “before”, and in all the Slavic languages that have cases this preposition governs only the genitive case, so it's not just a Polish phenomenon, the reasoning of this fact lying somewhere about 15 centuries ago.

Comment: @Lambie 'Genetive' is an older and more Latin-based spelling of 'genitive': https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genetive // Personally, I prefer the traditional *genitive*, but it's not a wild misspelling as it might appear.

Comment: @jogloran I know but I prefer the OP to make changes since that way they might remember them.

Comment: @cmw In English, if you use Latin, it should be in italics. No dictionary I have consulted spells it with an e like that.

Comment: @Lambie It's not Latin, I said it's based on Latin. And you're not seeing it in dictionaries because it's deprecated in modern language (although you will find it in the OED under *genitive* heading). You'll still see it in some grammar and reference works, but the preferred spelling today is *genitive*.

Comment: @cmw Etymology
genetive: Alternative form of genitive, compare Latin genetivus with genitivus. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genetive

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I linked you to that in my initial response. Your point is?

Comment: @cmw My point is that it does come from Latin. Though not as is. In any case, I would not use it.

Comment: @Lambie That's what I said. It's not Latin, it comes from Latin...

Comment: I don't know the exact historic reasoning, but I can suggest a rather logical _practical_ way to explain the gen. case there, a way for a learner to understand and memorize it. There are 3 similar preps. with gen. _Blisko_ (+ gen.) is “near”: _blisko sklepu_ “near [the] store”, so imagine _blisko_ means “in-the-outskirts”, and gen. case means “of-”, then _blisko sklepu_ is “in-the-outskirts of-[the]-store”. Similarly, _do_ means “to-the-outskirts”, so _do sklepu_ is “to-the-outskirts of-[the]-store”. Also, _od_ means “from-the-outskirts”, so _od sklepu_ is “from-the-outskirts of-[the]-store”.

Comment: @Lambie Oh I truly thought it was genetive, I guess I must have gotten confused because of the pronunciation. Although as others have said, it's apparently not that odd of a mistake considering the etymology of the word...

Comment: @ColinFine Because things always have logic. If you don't know about it here, that's fine.

Comment: @YellowSky Oh whoa, this was actually really helpful, thank you! If you'll post your explanation as an answer, I will upvote it and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Do*** is [found in all the Slavic languages](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/do) as a preposition with the meanings “[up] to” and “before”. In all the Slavic languages which have cases, this preposition governs only the genitive case, so it's not just a Polish phenomenon, the reasoning of this fact lying somewhere about 15 centuries ago when the Slavic languages split from Proto-Slavic.

I don't know the exact historic reasoning, but I can suggest a rather logical *practical* way to explain the genitive case usage with this preposition, a way for an English-speaking learner to understand and memorize it.

There are 3 similar prepositions in Polish that govern the genitive case, *blisko* “near”, *do* “to”, and *od* “from”. For my explanation, we need to slightly re-analyze their meanings. Originally, *blisko* (+ gen.) is “near”, e.g. *blisko sklepu* “near [the] store”. But let's assume ***blisko*** means “in-the-outskirts”, "in-the-vicinity", and assume the following genitive case means “of-”, then *blisko sklepu* comes to look like “in-the-vicinity of-[the]-store”, which is pretty English and quite logical. Similarly, ***do*** means “to-the-vicinity”, so *do sklepu* is “to-the-vicinity of-[the]-store”. And ***od*** means “from-the-vicinity”, so *od sklepu* is “from-the-*vicinity* of-[the]-store”. 
There's one more Polish locative preposition with genitive, ***z*** “from”, but it's not “from-the-vicinity” like *od*, it's “from-the-inside” ~ “from-the-interior”, so *z Polski* is “from-the-inside of-Poland”.

With a little bit of imagination one can find quite plausible justification practically for everything. Even if it wasn't like that historically, the pattern I suggest is quite productive. Mind, my explanation is for aligning the Polish cases with the English lack thereof, but it can also be aligned with other languages, with little effort.